# Losing reputation; answer no longer shows up in reputation report. What happened?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, profile-page

Something strange happened to my reputation. A few days ago I saw a sudden drop in my reputation, about 45 points. I figured this was due to some Reputation Recalc, but since I had some time on my hands I decided to dig into it.

I found that [one of the questions I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012732/cant-change-target-platform-to-any-cpu) on StackOverflow no longer showed up in my '/reputation' report. However, it still shows up on my profile page and the question is not deleted or moved, and no votes had been retracted. What happened here? I don't think that this is actually a bug, but that something else is going on (like the infamous fraud detection). Can someone please explain this to me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *question* does not show up in your reputation report because it's not yours.

The *answer*, however, does indeed show up. You have to search for post id 4014338 (the id of your answer) in your rep report, not the id of the question (4012732).

As to why your reputation dropped: There was no rep recalc done on your account, so the reputation drop must have been caused by someone else retracting their previously cast vote(s) on some of your posts (including unaccepting an answer).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my misinterpretation of the reputation report. I guess I'll have to live with the mysterious disappearance of the reputation.